# running java file from command prompt

Tags: java, windows

I made simple hello world app Java file.
I tried to compile it on command prompt in windows and went very well. 
but when I try to run it with Java the command prompt says the following error.
Error: Could not find or load main class "Project Name".
but when I checked the folder the file "Project Name".class is existed moreover I have main in it.

why I get this error ?

Edit :

file name : HelloWorldApp.java

code :

```
package helloworldapp;
/** * The HelloWorldApp class implements an application that 
    * simply prints "Hello World!" to standard output. */ 

public class HelloWorldApp
{ /* * @param args the command line arguments */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    { 
        System.out.println("Hello World!"); // Display the string
    } 
}
```

Comment: `Project Name.class` is present. Are you sure? A class name can't contains spaces.

Comment: Show us your `file name` and `code`

Comment: yes it have already exist and checked it

Comment: file name : HelloWorldApp.java

code : 

package helloworldapp;

/**
 * The HelloWorldApp class implements an application that
 * simply prints "Hello World!" to standard output.
 */
public class HelloWorldApp {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!"); // Display the string
    }
    
}

Comment: Technically when you run the program on the command prompt in windows, you are using Java. Are you trying to run this inside of an IDE or something else?

Comment: no, I run it from command prompt

Comment: Please add information to the question, not to comments. In any case, "Project Name" isn't your class, `HelloWorldApp` is.

Comment: Edit your .java file and remove "package helloworldapp;".  Then compile and run.  It will work.

Comment: When you get to studying "packages" pay careful attention.  The package naming structure must match the directory structure where the .class files are stored.  It's easy to muck up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the current directory to the class path when you run it, and included the package name

```
java -cp . helloworldapp.HelloWorldApp
```

Comment: you should also be in the directory above where the HelloWorldApp.class file resides.

Comment: If he's going to use a package then he has to get in bed with the whole package directory structure thingie -- not something to do Day 1.  Better to just eliminate the package statement in the code.

Comment: I removed the package statement in the code as @Hot Licks says and it goes very well !

thank you

Comment: I want to understand why when I add the package statement I get that ERROR ?

Comment: Packages in java corresponds to directories in the filesystem. In order to find the class `helloworldapp.HelloWorldApp`, java looks for the file `helloworldapp\HelloWorldApp.class` relative to the current directory (or directories in the CLASSPATH). If your command shell is already in the `helloworldapp` directory it won't be able to find it.